# Client wants to view progress of a GitHub repo

Tags: github, version-control, repository

Re: I'm relatively new to GitHub.

I'm working on a project stored in a GitHub repo, and the client would like the ability to check the progress of the project.

In the best case scenario, a solution would allow the client to view a file in the public repository that showed commits over time (addition/deletion, etc.), and included notes from each commit. The client is not assumed to have a prior knowledge of GitHub.

I've heard of "log files" being useful for this, but I've seen differing answers on how to use these files.

What options are out there? I know of GitKraken, though I'm trying to make the solution minimally involved for the client. Would appreciate any thoughts or suggestions

(Once again, I would be using GitKraken, but it's too complicated for the average user and requires an outside client to download a program (not ideal).)

Answer (score 1):

What do you want that is different to the standard commits page?

[https://github.com/{username}/{reponame}/commits/](https://github.com/%7Busername%7D/%7Breponame%7D/commits/)

Comment: Nothing, that's the type of feature I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have told us mighty little about what you have: is this a personal repository or a repository that belongs to an organization? If it is personal, is it public or private?

If it is personal and public, then obviously, the only thing your client needs is the URL of your repository.

If it is personal and private, then the only thing you can do is add them as a collaborator, in which case they will have write access to the repository. (This is a GitHub limitation on personal private repositories, see [GitHub Docs - Permission levels for a personal account repository](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-personal-account-settings/permission-levels-for-a-personal-account-repository))

If it is an organizational repository, then you can assign your client a role. For more information about this, see [GitHub Docs - Repository roles for an organization](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-user-access-to-your-organizations-repositories/repository-roles-for-an-organization)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to be more specific in the future. I'm looking for the simplest way to have a non-GitHub user view the commit activity on a repository, and I think using descriptive notes for each commit and referring them to the standard commits page will do the trick.